# CSS flex shrink images in column

Tags: css, flexbox

How do I automatically shrink flex child's height in `flex-direction: column` so they **all fit in** parent's height?

I tried `flex-shrink` but it didn't help.

Is it even possible?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

- Edited the title.
- Children are images, I need to automatically change their height so they fit within parent and cause no overflow.

Comment: can you please describe in more detail what exactly you wanna do? If possible draw a rough sketch of what you are trying to achieve and post it here, so that we can help you better

Comment: I updated the post, the childs are images and I want them to change their height so they'll fit within their parrent and won't cause an overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try using `flex-wrap`

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bloc {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
  <div class="bloc">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.flex {
   display: flex;
}

.block {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 5px;
   border: 2px red solid;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
  <img class="block" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196"/>
</div>
```